# How to add a LAN printer in Azure VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, printer, azure, local

I have an Azure VM equipped with Windows Server 2019 and I want to add a local network printer to this VM.

Note that I connect to this VM through an RDP player.

Comment: What have you tried already? Make sure to [edit] the question accordingly.